# Symfony import jquery & js script

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, twig

I downloaded jquery into my src/.../Resouces/public/js folder and created a simple script called blogcreate.js in the same directory.

My twig template file is attempting to include both js files with the following code:

```
{% block javascripts %}
    {% javascripts '@BloggerBlogBundle/Resources/public/js/*' %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

Blog.js contains the following code:

```
(function ($){
    alert('Responding!');
});
```

The trouble is my network tab shows both script but my blogcreate file has a 304 status - which I guess is why my alert box doesn't show up.

Would appreciate it if anyone can tell me what I'm missing.

PS:

I had to include the following in the bundle section of my app/config/config.yml file:

```
assetic:
    debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ BloggerBlogBundle ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

304 is "Not Modified" and means that your browser already has a current version of that file. It's not an error.

Your script does not run because its only function is never called.

```
(function ($){
    alert('Responding!');
});
```

ought to be either

```
(function ($){
    alert('Responding!');
})(jQuery);
```

or possibly:

```
$(function (){
    alert('Responding!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Tomalak. I missed that